# How do I reference a documented Python function parameter using Sphinx markup?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docstring

I'd like to reference a previously-documented function parameter elsewhere in a Python docstring.  Consider the following (admittedly completely artificial) example:

```
def foo(bar):
    """Perform foo action
    :param bar: The bar parameter
    """

    def nested():
        """Some nested function that depends on enclosing scope's bar parameter.
        I'd like to reference function foo's bar parameter here
        with a link, is that possible?"""
        return bar * bar

    # ...
    return nested()
```

Is there a simple way to embed a parameter reference using Sphinx markup, or will this happen automagically?

(I'm a complete Sphinx newbie.  I've been scanning the Sphinx docs and haven't found an answer to this question, or an example demonstrating proper markup.)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I've just built an extension to accomplish this task.  So far it seems to be working with standalone HTML build and additionally with readthedocs (after some more tweaks).

the extension is available at: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sphinx-paramlinks/.

I'm rolling it out right now for the Alembic and SQLAlchemy projects.  ([sample](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/ops.html#alembic.operations.Operations.drop_column)).

I take disagreement with the suggestion that linking to params means the docs are too lengthy.  The Python standard library is a poor example here as stdlib functions are necessarily granular and simple.  Software that is accomplishing a more coarse-grained task, where a single function rides on top of a complex problem to be solved, will often have parameters that require a lot more explanation; this explanation is often quite valuable as the solution to a particular problem elsewhere, and therefore being able to link to it is very important.

Comment: This is great, but doesn't appear to work with Googly docstrings (such as those used with `sphinxcontrib.napoleon`). Is that something that could be made to work?

Comment: depends on how it works.  If it rewrites the params straight to restructured text, sphinx-paramlinks wouldn't really have much to offer that out of the box, as it relies upon parsing the raw RST before sphinx gets control of it.   This is largely to avoid having to manipulate the internals of sphinx.  it would be **much much much** better if Sphinx just implemented this feature natively at this point.  I'm hoping my extension makes it obvious how desperately needed this feature is.

Comment: Thanks. I expected something like that (it makes sense). And I agree with you that this is a desperately needed feature.

Comment: I installed with pip, and trying it, I get this error from Sphinx: `Could not import extension sphinx-paramlinks (exception: No module named 'sphinx-paramlinks')`, while `pip list` says it's installed. I'm using Python 3.4.

Comment: OK, I got it. The package's name is `sphinx-paramlinks` but the extension's name to be added to `conf.py` is `sphinx_paramlinks` (underscore vs dahs).

Comment: Love this, but which it worked with Googly docstrings. Any chance of that (now that some time has passed)?

Comment: Also: this give import errors when I try to build on Read The Docs (`No module named sphinx_paramlinks`).

Comment: Doesn't work properly with `:type paramname: int` -- eats my type definitions without warnings... Sphinx (sphinx-build) 1.6.3

Answer (score 38):

There is no simple way to get a direct reference to a parameter of a function with `sphinx` and I don't know an extension for this problem.

The [documentation of the python domain](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#cross-referencing-python-objects) explains which objects can be cross referenced.

A possible way to give the user a reference to parameter `bar` of function `foo` would be

```
See parameter ``bar`` in :func:`foo`.
```

Maybe a direct reference would be possible by writing an extension.

Answer (score 2):

For those, that want to use `sphinx-paramlinks` with `sphinx.ext.napoleon` here is a patch. Simple find the right fragment in the `sphinx-paramlinks` source code (sphinx_paramlinks\sphinx_paramlinks.py, somewhere around line 50) and replace it with this:

```
def cvt(m):
    directive, modifier, objname, paramname = (
        m.group(1), m.group(2) or '', name, m.group(3))
    if directive == 'param':
        refname = _refname_from_paramname(paramname, strip_markup=True)
        item = ('single', '%s (%s parameter)' % (refname, objname),
                '%s.params.%s' % (objname, refname), '')
        if LooseVersion(__version__) >= LooseVersion('1.4.0'):
            item += (None,)
        doc_idx.append(item)
    return ":%s %s_sphinx_paramlinks_%s.%s:" % (
        directive, modifier, objname, paramname)
return re.sub(r'^:(param|type) ([^:]+? )?([^:]+?):', cvt, line)
```

Note: remember about the right indent.

I'm not a Sphinx specialist, but this seems to get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

Not to say that [sphinx-paramlinks](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sphinx-paramlinks/) is not a fine solution, but I'm a bit
stubborn about adding *more* extensions to my project.

You won't get the benefit of the visual highlight, or an anchor icon, which is a bummer, but a reStructuredText [hyperlink target](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#hyperlink-targets) before that section at least gets you close:

```py
    def from_existing_id(cls, jobid, **kwargs):
        """Instantiates a new :class:`Job` object from an existing job ID.

        :param jobid: the ID of the previous job
        :param kwargs: keyword arguments supported by :meth:`deserialize`,
            *e.g.*, :ref:`ignore_missing <deserialize_params>`.
        """
        ⋮

    # elsewhere
    def deserialize(self, filename, copy_inputs=False, ignore_missing=False):
        """Reads a disk file into the current :class:`Job` object's config.
    
        .. _deserialize_params:

        :param filename: the filename to read from to disk
        :param copy_inputs: copy input files to output directory
        :param ignore_missing: don't bail if input files are missing
        """
        ⋮
```

The longer your parameter list gets, the less useful this becomes, though.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for a way to link directly to the `bar` definition of `foo` then your documentation is too lengthy or you are asking your reader to ignore the forest for one tree or some combination of the two.

Taking an example from [defaultdict Examples](http://docs.python.org//library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples):

```
Setting the :attr:`default_factory` to :class:`int` makes the
:class:`defaultdict` useful for counting (like a bag or multiset in other
languages):
```

if I can't be bothered to read five sentences into [collections.defaultdict](http://docs.python.org//library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects) to find the meaning of `default_factory` I probably don't deserve to be lead there.

Note that the attribute reference syntax is the same as in the section above:

```
The first argument provides the initial value for the :attr:`default_factory`
attribute; it defaults to ``None``.
```

but it looks like Sphinx doesn't reach out of the current section scope and so renders the later reference as styled text rather than as an anchor. It would not surprise me if this was intentional.

Comment: Perhaps my original question/example was overly simplistic. (That's what happens when I post questions in a sleep-deprived state :D) I've updated the question and code example to help clarify my motivation.