# Sphinx: Link to a method of a class in another module in Python docstring

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx, docstring

I want to add a link to a method of a class in one module (say `module_2.py`) in another method in another module ( say `module_1.py`). I want the link to work in Sphinx.

Suppose:

**module_1.py**

```
class ABC:
   def foo(self):
      """
      See docstring of module_2.py bar():<link to bar() in module_2.py>
      """
      print("foo")
```

**module_2.py**

```
class XYZ:
    def bar(self):
    """
    This function prints hello.
    """
    print("hello")
```

Comment: You have answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21289806/link-to-class-method-in-python-docstring, and more here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168178/how-do-i-reference-a-documented-python-function-parameter-using-sphinx-markup

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Link to class method in python docstring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21289806/link-to-class-method-in-python-docstring)

Answer (score 11):

To truly get a hyperlink, your method reference needs to contain a complete path. The simplest way to create any link is using the [`:obj:`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#role-py:obj) cross-reference:

```
"""See docstring of :obj:`path.to.module_2.XYZ.bar`."""
```

> See docstring of `path.to.module_2.XYZ.bar`.

You can shorten the anchor text to just the last element of the path with the [tild `~`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#cross-referencing-syntax):

```
"""See docstring of :obj:`~path.to.module_2.XYZ.bar`."""
```

> See docstring of `bar`.

Or specify [custom text](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#cross-referencing-syntax) like so:

```
"""See docstring of :obj:`XYZ.bar <path.to.module_2.XYZ.bar>`."""
```

> See docstring of `XYZ.bar`.

This is perhaps the most reader-friendly solution.

For completeness, note that `:obj:` is a general untyped reference, but Sphinx provides [several other categories of cross-reference](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#cross-referencing-python-objects) with some specific behaviours.

Answer (score 8):

You can write:

```
class ABC:
  def foo(self):
    """
    See docstring of :py:meth:`bar() <XYZ.bar>` in :py:mod:`module_2`.
    """
    print("foo")
```

The shown markup uses a **role** to link to a documented element. If Python is the default domain for your documentation, then `:py` can be omitted. The role `meth` links to a method name. A dotted name can be used. Likewise, `mod` links to a module name. The content of a role is written wetween ``` `` ```. The content (logical link name can have a differnet visual content. Therefore the logical link name is written in `<>`. Example: `` :role:`text <logical name>` ``.

Further information: http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/domains.html#role-py:meth

Comment: I don't see the path to `bar()` in it's docstring. Suppose you prohibited to write `in :py:mod:`module_2``